# SVG - resizing a rectangle positioned at an angle

Tags: svg, rotation

All,

I have a SVG rectangle in my application which can be stretched horizontally by dragging the end bar (left & right) on either side of the rectangle. The rectangle can be

(1) resized (by stretching as per above),

(2)dragged,

(3)& rotated.

Everything works fine, however, one strange experience is that when I rotate the rectangle to a degree close to 90, & then try to resize the rectangle, it starts stretching from the opposite border of the rectangle instead of the original borders. (here is the image):

[image: rendition of functionality]

It appears to be getting confused between left and right when I use the rotate function.

Here is the revised HTML, JS & SVG:

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
<!--        <script type="text/javascript" src="CPolyline.js">

        </script>-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <object id="oo" data="rect2.svg" style="position:fixed;width: 800px;height:800px;bottom:-100px;right: 375px;">

    </object>
        path: <input type="button" id="path" onclick="X()">
        path2: <input type="button" id="path2" onclick="Y()">
     <input type="button" value="Rotate" onclick="Rotate1()">


        <script type="text/javascript">
            var ob=document.getElementById("oo")

            var svgDoc=null;
            var svgRoot=null;
            var MyGroupObjectsObj = null;
            var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
            var dragTarget = null;
            var rectTemplate = null;
            var grabPoint = null;
            var clientPoint = null;
            var rectX = null;
            var rectY = null;
            var rectWidth = null;
            var rectHeight = null;
            var arr=new Array();
            var resizingLeft = false;
            var resizingRight = false;
            var rectrot=null

            ob.addEventListener("load", function(){

                svgDoc=ob.contentDocument;

                svgRoot=svgDoc.documentElement;
                grabPoint = svgRoot.createSVGPoint();
                clientPoint = svgRoot.createSVGPoint();
                rectTemplate = svgDoc.getElementById('rectTemplate')

       rectrot=svgDoc.getElementById("rect1")



}, false)



var angel=0


function Rotate1()
{

       angel=angel+10
       //alert(rectrot)

       var c=rectTemplate.getAttribute("transform");
       var widt=Number(rectTemplate.getAttribute("width"))/2;

        var hie=Number(rectTemplate.getAttribute("height"))/2
        var tran=c.match(/[\d\.]+/g);
        var newxpo=Number(tran[0])+widt;
        var newypo=Number(tran[1])+hie;
        var r=Math.tan((newxpo)/(newypo))
      rectTemplate.parentNode.setAttribute("transform","translate("+newxpo+" "+newypo+")"+"rotate("+angel+") translate("+(newxpo*-1)+" "+(newypo*-1)+")");



}


function MouseDown(evt)
{

  var targetElement = evt.target;
       var checkForResizeAttempt = false;

        if (targetElement == rectTemplate)
        {
            //arr.push(cir ,cir1,rectTemplate)

               dragTarget = targetElement;
               checkForResizeAttempt = true;

                       var transMatrix = dragTarget.getCTM();


        grabPoint.x = evt.clientX - Number(transMatrix.e);
        grabPoint.y = evt.clientY - Number(transMatrix.f);

        }

        var transMatrix = dragTarget.getCTM();



//var transMatrix = dragTarget.getCTM().inverse();

        grabPoint.x = evt.clientX - Number(transMatrix.e);
        grabPoint.y = evt.clientY - Number(transMatrix.f);

        if (window.console) console.log(grabPoint.x + " " + grabPoint.y);
        if (window.console) console.log(evt.clientX + " " + evt.clientY);

        if (checkForResizeAttempt)
        {
          clientPoint.x = evt.clientX;
          clientPoint.y = evt.clientY;
          rectX = Number(dragTarget.getAttributeNS(null, "x"));
          rectY = Number(dragTarget.getAttributeNS(null, "y"));
          rectWidth = Number(dragTarget.getAttributeNS(null, "width"));
          rectHeight = Number(dragTarget.getAttributeNS(null, "height"));

          if ((grabPoint.x - rectX) < 10)
          {
            resizingLeft = true;
          }
          else if (((rectX + rectWidth) - grabPoint.x) < 10)
          {
            resizingRight = true;
          }

          if (resizingLeft || resizingRight)
          {
            dragTarget.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke","green");
          }
          else
          {
            dragTarget.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke","black");
          }
        }
      }

function MouseMove(evt)
{
evt.stopPropagation();
 if (dragTarget == null)
      {
        return;
      }
      if (resizingLeft)
      {
        if (window.console) console.log(evt.clientX + " " + evt.clientY);
        deltaX = (clientPoint.x - evt.clientX);
        if (window.console) console.log("deltaX = " + deltaX);
        dragTarget.setAttributeNS(null,"width",rectWidth + deltaX);
        dragTarget.setAttributeNS(null,"x",rectX - deltaX);
      }
      else if (resizingRight)
      {
        deltaX = (clientPoint.x - evt.clientX);
        if (window.console) console.log("rectWidth = " + rectWidth + " deltaX = " + deltaX);
        dragTarget.setAttributeNS(null,"width",rectWidth - deltaX);


      }
      else
      {


        var newXX = evt.clientX-grabPoint.x;
        var newYX = evt.clientY-grabPoint.y;


        dragTarget.setAttributeNS(null,'transform','translate(' + newXX + ',' + newYX + ')');
      }

}
function MouseUp(evt)
{
  evt.stopPropagation();
   if (dragTarget == null)
      {
        return;
      }
      resizingLeft = false;
      resizingRight = false;
      resizingTop = false;
      resizingBottom = false;
     // var transMatrix = dragTarget.getCTM().inverse();
      dragTarget.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke","blue");
      dragTarget = null;


}


        </script>
    </body>
</html>



--



=======SVG ====

<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">

<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:a="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeSVGViewerExtensions/3.0/"
     x="0px" y="0px" width="612px" height="792px" xml:space="preserve"
onmousedown="ecmascript:top.MouseDown(evt)"
onmousemove="ecmascript:top.MouseMove(evt)"
onmouseup="ecmascript:top.MouseUp(evt)">




<g id="rect1">
  <rect id="rectTemplate" x="0" y="0" stroke="blue" width="100" height="30" />

 </g>
```

Comment: It would really help if you posted a pared-down-but-working full example (e.g. include the SVG file). Also, your code indentation needs some serious formatting loving compared to how you have pasted it.

Comment: Thanks Phrogz, I'll see if I can post a pared down version of the code.

Comment: Updated the code to better refect the bits that need the attention. Best,

Comment: Is this live somewhere??

Comment: No not yet Garet... but I think we might have just solved it, give me a day or two and I'll share our findings... cheers

Answer (score 5):

I have posted a sample of dragging and resizing transformed SVG rects in my answer here:
[SVG coordinates with transform matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850821/svg-coordinates-with-transform-matrix/5223921#5223921)

You can see the working example on my site here:
http://phrogz.net/svg/drag_under_transformation.xhtml

The key is to:

1. When you start dragging (`mousedown`) record the mouse location (in SVG global space).
2. During dragging (`mousemove`) calculate the offset (in SVG global space) for the drag, and then
3. Transform that offset from global space into the local space of the object, and use that to inform your changes.

This works regardless of the transformation hierarchy applied (as shown in my example).

Comment: THanx phrogz, my resizing is worinkg right,But when i rotate the rectangle and want to resize it again the rectangle is moving other direction(opposite to cursor position) because its co-ordinates is moved from its original location...help me after rotation resizing

Comment: @AbdulRauf My code and example suffers from no such problem. If I get more time I'll look to analyze your code, but what I'm supplying is working code.

Comment: Thanks Phrogz. We are doing the same and achieving the same result too. However, in our scenario, in addition to the 'user being able to drag at the ends of the rectangle and stretching it', they can also rotate the rectangle. The problem stems from the rotation, i.e. when we rotate the rectangle to a degree even a little greater than 20, all the resizing functionality turns on its head.

Comment: @Kayote You're saying that my code has a problem when you change an angle to a large amount? I haven't seen that.

Comment: No, the problem lies with our code. Your code is fine upto the functionality already present but if you were to add the code to try changing the angle of the rectangle (say using an input box) and then manually resizing, I think you will find the it does not function as it should, i.e. it will resize in the opposite directions.

Comment: The `getTransformToElement` is depreciated in Chrome Canary: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5736166087196672.  A workaround is `toElem.getScreenCTM().inverse().multiply(fromElem.getScreenCTM())`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to change your code to rotate the shape around the center of the shape?

[Here is an excerpt](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformAttribute) of the W3C draft on transform:

```
rotate(<rotate-angle> [<cx> <cy>]),
which specifies a rotation by <rotate-angle> degrees about a given point.

If optional parameters <cx> and <cy> are not supplied, the rotate is about the origin of the current user coordinate system. 

The operation corresponds to the matrix [cos(a) sin(a) -sin(a) cos(a) 0 0].

If optional parameters <cx> and <cy> are supplied, the rotate is about the point (cx, cy). 

The operation represents the equivalent of the following specification: 
translate(<cx>, <cy>) rotate(<rotate-angle>) translate(-<cx>, -<cy>).
```

If you set cx and cy to the center of your ribbon, this may help from what context I can pick up from your code.

Comment: i doing the same thing to rotate but when i rotate fist time rectangle its changed its coordinates and not resize ...

Comment: Thanks Garet, I finally had a chance to go back to this issue. We are passing the 'rectangle into a group' and then rotating the group from the centre. Here is the code:

rectTemplate.parentNode.setAttribute("transform","translate("+newxpo+" "+newypo+")"+"rotate("+angel+") translate("+(newxpo*-1)+" "+(newypo*-1)+")");

Comment: Garet, Ive added to the above original question, in addition to the reply to your post and Phrogz.

Comment: There are a number of places in the code you might consider using a sign variable to handle cases where change in x,y can be negative or positive. i,e: `myValue.x = BaseX + sign*OffsetX;` where sign is either -1 or 1. This isn't always helpful but might be for you. Are you having the exact same issues with the updated code?