# SVG coordinates with transform matrix

Tags: html, svg

I want to implement the functionality like svg-edit on rectangle element

1. Rotate rectangle
2. Resizing
3. Drag

Rotating the SVG rectangle it works fine, but when I want to resize the rectangle it has a problem. The coordinates are not working right; I use the transform matrix to rotate
`targetelement.setAttribute(transform,rotate(45,cx,cy))`
but when the element has been rotated the coordinates are moved. I'm also using `inverse` function to inverse the transform matrix it resolves the problem but its not working with drag function.

Comment: The problem description is hard to understand -- could you please describe more precisely (including code) what you did, what you wanted to happen, and what happened instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SVG - resizing a rectangle positioned at an angle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732624/svg-resizing-a-rectangle-positioned-at-an-angle)

Answer (score 111):

I have created a working example of what I believe you are describing on my site here:
http://phrogz.net/svg/drag_under_transformation.xhtml

In general, you convert the mouse cursor into the local space of an object by:

1. Creating a `mousemove` event handler:

   ```js
   var svg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
   document.documentElement.addEventListener('mousemove',function(evt){
     ...
   },false);
   ```
2. In that event handler, convert the mouse coordinates (in pixels) into the global space of your SVG document:

   ```js
   var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();
   pt.x = evt.clientX;
   pt.y = evt.clientY;
   var globalPoint = pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
   ```
3. Convert the global point into the space of the object you are dragging:

   ```js
   var globalToLocal = dragObject.getTransformToElement(svg).inverse();
   var inObjectSpace = globalPoint.matrixTransform( globalToLocal );
   ```

For Stack Overflow posterity, here's the full source of my SVG+XHTML demo (in case my site is down):

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"><head> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Dragging Transformed SVG Elements</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
  html, body {
    background:#eee; margin:0;
    user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -webkit-user-select:none;
  }
  p { margin:0.5em; text-align:center }
  svg {
    position:absolute; top:5%; left:5%; width:90%; height:90%;
    background:#fff; border:1px solid #ccc
  }
  svg rect { stroke:#333 }
  svg .drag { cursor:move }
  svg .sizer { opacity:0.3; fill:#ff0; stroke:#630;}
  #footer {
    position:absolute; bottom:0.5em; margin-bottom:0;
    width:40em; margin-left:-20em; left:50%; color:#666;
    font-style:italic; font-size:85%
  }
  #dragcatch { position:absolute; left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0; z-index:-1}
</style>
</head><body>
<p>Showing how to drag points inside a transformation hierarchy.</p>
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" baseProfile="full">
  <g transform="scale(1.2,0.8)">
    <rect transform="translate(50,20) rotate(30)"
     class="drag resize" x="50" y="30" width="50" height="30" fill="#69c" />
    <rect class="drag resize" x="5" y="5" width="90" height="50" fill="#c66" />
  </g>
</svg>
<p id="footer">
  Copyright © 2011 <a href="mailto:!@phrogz.net">Gavin Kistner</a>. 
  Comments/criticisms welcome.
</p>
<script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
  var svg   = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
  var svgNS = svg.getAttribute('xmlns');
  var pt    = svg.createSVGPoint();

  function createOn(root,name,prop){
    var el = document.createElementNS(svgNS,name);
    for (var a in prop) if (prop.hasOwnProperty(a)) el.setAttribute(a,prop[a]);
    return root.appendChild(el);
  }

  function rectCorner(rect){
    pt.x = rect.x.animVal.value + rect.width.animVal.value;
    pt.y = rect.y.animVal.value + rect.height.animVal.value;
    return pt.matrixTransform(rect.getTransformToElement(svg));
  }

  function pointIn(el,x,y){
    pt.x = x; pt.y = y;
    return pt.matrixTransform(el.getTransformToElement(svg).inverse());
  }

  function cursorPoint(evt){
    pt.x = evt.clientX; pt.y = evt.clientY;
    return pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
  }

  // Make all rects resizable before drag, so the drag handles become drag
  for (var a=svg.querySelectorAll('rect.resize'),i=0,len=a.length;i<len;++i){
    (function(rect){
      var dot = createOn(svg,'circle',{'class':'drag sizer',cx:0,cy:0,r:5});
      var moveDotToRect = function(){
        var corner = rectCorner(rect);
        dot.setAttribute('cx',corner.x);
        dot.setAttribute('cy',corner.y);
      }
      moveDotToRect();
      rect.addEventListener('dragged',moveDotToRect,false);
      dot.addEventListener('dragged',function(){
        var rectXY = pointIn(rect,dot.cx.animVal.value,dot.cy.animVal.value);
        var w = Math.max( rectXY.x-rect.x.animVal.value, 1 );
        var h = Math.max( rectXY.y-rect.y.animVal.value, 1 );
        rect.setAttribute('width', w);
        rect.setAttribute('height',h);
      },false);
    })(a[i]);
  }

  for (var a=svg.querySelectorAll('.drag'),i=0,len=a.length;i<len;++i){
    (function(el){
      var onmove; // make inner closure available for unregistration
      el.addEventListener('mousedown',function(e){
        el.parentNode.appendChild(el); // move to top
        var x = el.tagName=='circle' ? 'cx' : 'x';
        var y = el.tagName=='circle' ? 'cy' : 'y';
        var mouseStart   = cursorPoint(e);
        var elementStart = { x:el[x].animVal.value, y:el[y].animVal.value };
        onmove = function(e){
          var current = cursorPoint(e);
          pt.x = current.x - mouseStart.x;
          pt.y = current.y - mouseStart.y;
          var m = el.getTransformToElement(svg).inverse();
          m.e = m.f = 0;
          pt = pt.matrixTransform(m);
          el.setAttribute(x,elementStart.x+pt.x);
          el.setAttribute(y,elementStart.y+pt.y);
          var dragEvent = document.createEvent("Event");
          dragEvent.initEvent("dragged", true, true);
          el.dispatchEvent(dragEvent);
        };
        document.body.addEventListener('mousemove',onmove,false);
      },false);
      document.body.addEventListener('mouseup',function(){
        document.body.removeEventListener('mousemove',onmove,false);
      },false);
    })(a[i]);
  }
]]></script>
<div id="dragcatch"></div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: thanx phrogz.... after rotation i want to resize the rectangle again like svg-edit....i think my rectangle co-ords is changed when i rotate

Comment: Thanks for the code. I was having trouble figuring out how to get the transform value without using getAttribute, but then I saw the getTransformToElement() method in your code. Cheers. :)

Comment: Clean, simple, works. With such poor svg documentation on the web this answer really stands out.

Comment: Quite awesome, Phrogz. There aren't enough good examples on building graphical manipulation tools using SVG, which I imagine is a fairly common use case. @AbdulRauf, can you accept this answer?

Comment: @Hypher Thanks! Note that Abdul was last seen on S/O over 2.5 years ago, so it seems unlikely that s/he will notice your request. :D

Comment: Where did you find information about getScreenCTM and getCTM? I cannot find them in the SVG TR or similar, also search enginges return very few results. Are those standardised functions, i.e. can we rely on browsers implementing them?

Comment: @SimonA.Eugster They are part of the SVG 1.1 spec, and are well supported. See: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/types.html#__svg__SVGLocatable__getCTM

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Here is a very simple fiddle for coordinate system conversion. https://jsfiddle.net/milindaaruna/vu2rvz81/1/

Comment: FYI the example is currently throwing an error in Chrome: drag_under_transformation.xhtml:56Uncaught TypeError: rect.getTransformToElement is not a function

Comment: This is fantastic. Thanks! Out of curiosity, what is the `dragcatch` div for?

Comment: Note that [SVGPoint is now deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGPoint). New code should use [DOMPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMPoint). (However, some browser devs want to keep SVGPoint).

Answer (score 4):

For those who use Chrome please add the following lines after

```
var pt    = svg.createSVGPoint();

SVGElement.prototype.getTransformToElement = SVGElement.prototype.getTransformToElement || function(elem) {
  return elem.getScreenCTM().inverse().multiply(this.getScreenCTM());
};
```

More info here: https://github.com/cpettitt/dagre-d3/issues/202

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question.

Comment: Yes but the answer doesn't work on Crome browser without it!

Comment: Answers must answer the question, this is a comment on an existing answer which is not allowed here. Once you have 50 rep you can add it as a comment to the existing answer.

Answer (score 0):

While [Phrogz answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850821/svg-coordinates-with-transform-matrix/5223921#5223921) is very good and complete, and there still may be value in the deprecated [SVGPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGPoint) solution for some, it may be instructive to present the [DOMPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMPoint) alternative here in brief.

All other particulars aside, where before we had:

```js
var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();
pt.x = evt.clientX;
pt.y = evt.clientY;
var globalPoint = pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
```

we can now do:

```js
var pt = new DOMPointReadOnly(evt.clientX, evt.clientY);
var globalPoint = pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
```