# SVG: when to use animVal / baseVal

Tags: html, svg

When does animVal and baseVal of an SVG element differ? When is the appropriate time to use them to get the correct value? The verbatim difference can be read based on [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html), but I am more concerned when all these values can differ. Any transformation, or scaling affects it?

Form another post at SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850821/svg-coordinates-with-transform-matrix)

```
function rectCorner(rect){
    pt.x = rect.x.animVal.value + rect.width.animVal.value;
    pt.y = rect.y.animVal.value + rect.height.animVal.value;
    return pt.matrixTransform(rect.getTransformToElement(svg));
}
```

What is the rationale using animVal here?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

These properties only vary when using the [SVG Animation Elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/animate.html#AnimationElements) `<animate>`, `<set>`, `<animateColor>`, `<animateTransform>`, or `<animateMotion>`. As noted in the link you provided, `baseVal` and `animVal` will be the same if there is not explicit animation being applied.

The rationale for using `animVal` in the above is that it will be the same as `baseVal` under most circumstances, but on the off chance that animation *is* applied and running it will represent the current value of the attribute instead of the value at some point in the past.