# HowTo select svg-objects inside a drawnrect d3

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, d3.js

I'm creating a little graphic editor, where the user (by now) could insert some "symbols", that consist of some svg-elements, grouped inside a g-tag.
Additionally, he could draw lines in different colors yet.

By now I am able to select single drawn lines and Symbols and I also could select more objects by clicking on them, while Holding the Control-key. (For those, who are interrested in it, a selected object gets a class "selected", so I could find them programatically by `d3.select('.selected')`.)

My new Goal ist to draw a rectangle with the mouse over such Elements and select the Elements inside the rectangle.
For this, I catch the pointerdown-event, where I add a rectangle to the svg-box and scale it inside pointermove-event.

Attached, a simple Video of my actual Version.

I have two Questions by now:

1) How can I avoid that the Elements are higlited like selected text while moving the mouse with pressed left button? (you can see the flickering in the Video) 
Is there perhaps something like `event.preventDefault();` to do so?

2) ...and that is the greater problem…
Is drawing a rectangle a good way to do this and how can i quickly calculate which elements are inside this rectangle? Is there perhaps a specialized function in d3, that I didn't find yet?

EDIT: for clarification, I attached a screenshot of the svg-structur of a Symbol and a line:
[image: Sample]

[Simple sample video](https://youtu.be/QqVZXvpmNp8)

CodePen example: https://codepen.io/Telefisch/pen/LoEReP

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
svgDrawing = document.getElementById('drawing');
  svgDrawing.addEventListener('pointerdown', mouseButtonPressed);
  svgDrawing.addEventListener('pointerup', mouseButtonReleased);
  svgDrawing.addEventListener('pointermove', mouseMove);
}) ...
```

Additional question:

What's the difference between 
`svg_children[i].className.baseVal += ' selected';` and 
`svg_children[i].classList.add('selected')`
I have some problems that baseVal seems not to be stored inside the dom? If I use it that way, I couldn't see the class in the elements-pane of the developer-window, but it pops up at the symbol. If I use ClassList.add, I can see the class in the Elements-Pane also. 

Screenshot:[image: Screenshot]
As you can see, the yellow-marked seems to have the class in the popup but not in the Elements-code. This is added by `svg_children[i].className.baseVal += ' selected';`
The red-marked 'selected'-class was added by `svg_children[i].classList.add('selected')`

Thanks so far, 
Carsten

Comment: Could you share a minimal reproducible example? i.e. a CodePen or JSFiddle etc.?

Comment: Hmm… I don't know exactly, what you want to see? Of Course I could create some simlyfied example but what do you hope to see?

Comment: In general, a simplified example in a CodePen type sandbox to look at and to solve that way is best - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask even if it is a simplified or anonymized version of your app, then we can provide a concrete answer. If you add real code then we know what you have tried so far, can reproduce it, can test it and can solve it.

Comment: I will do my best, only tooks an hour or so. I don't get Java to run on codepen.

Comment: Why does this not work in Codepen?: 
`$(document).ready(function () {
  console.log("hier");
})`  
`https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js` already added.

Comment: Works for me: https://codepen.io/Alexander9111/pen/MWYRzqj (added https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js)

Comment: Seems to be an Edge Problem. Chrome works.  Now I will create an example.

Comment: Ok, here it is: [link](https://codepen.io/Telefisch/pen/LoEReP)  in chrome the problem with the flickering doesn't exist so I only need a hint to calculate the elements inside the rectangle.

Comment: check out my answer and demo: https://codepen.io/Alexander9111/pen/XWJQoPP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have a solution for you, using `.getClientBoundingRect()` of the svg elements and the `<rect.selectionBox/>` to find out if your box is overlapping them etc.

Demo - https://codepen.io/Alexander9111/pen/XWJQoPP:

[image]

Code:

```
var svgDrawing = document.getElementById('drawing');
var pointerOrigin;
var point = svgDrawing.createSVGPoint();
var drawRectToSelect
var raster = 10;

$(document).ready(function () {
  svgDrawing = document.getElementById('drawing');
  svg_rect = svgDrawing.getBoundingClientRect();
  console.log("svg_rect", svg_rect);
  g = document.getElementById("437");
  //svg_children = g.childNodes;
  svg_children = g.querySelectorAll("*");
  console.log(svg_children);
  svgDrawing.addEventListener('pointerdown', e => mouseButtonPressed(e));
  svgDrawing.addEventListener('pointerup', e => mouseButtonReleased(e));
  svgDrawing.addEventListener('pointermove', e => mouseMove(e));
})

function mouseButtonPressed(evt) {
  pointerOrigin = getPointFromEvent(evt);
  if(evt.button === 0)
    {
      drawRectToSelect = d3.select('#drawing')
      .append('rect')
      .attr("id","temp_selection")
      .classed('selectionBox', true)
      .attr("x", Math.round(pointerOrigin.x / raster) * raster)
            .attr("y", Math.round(pointerOrigin.y / raster) * raster)
            .attr("height", raster)
            .attr("width", raster);
    }
}

function mouseMove(evt) {
    if (!drawRectToSelect) { return; }

    evt.preventDefault();  //Verschieben der gesamten Seite unterbinden

    var pointerPosition = getPointFromEvent(evt);
    if (drawRectToSelect) {
        drawRectToSelect
            .attr("width", Math.round((pointerPosition.x - pointerOrigin.x) / raster) * raster)
            .attr("height", Math.round((pointerPosition.y - pointerOrigin.y) / raster) * raster);
    }
}

function elementIsInside(el, box){
  var result = false;
  el_rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  box_rect = box.getBoundingClientRect();
  // console.log("rects_" + el.tagName, el_rect, box_rect)
  // console.log("rects_" + el.tagName, el, box)
  if (el_rect.right >= box_rect.left && el_rect.right <= box_rect.right
     && el_rect.bottom >= box_rect.top && el_rect.bottom <= box_rect.bottom){
    result = true;
  } else if (el_rect.left >= box_rect.left && el_rect.left <= box_rect.right
     && el_rect.bottom >= box_rect.top && el_rect.bottom <= box_rect.bottom){
    result = true;
  } else if (el_rect.right >= box_rect.left && el_rect.right <= box_rect.right
     && el_rect.top >= box_rect.top && el_rect.top <= box_rect.bottom){
    result = true;
  } else if (el_rect.left >= box_rect.left && el_rect.left <= box_rect.right
     && el_rect.top >= box_rect.top && el_rect.top <= box_rect.bottom){
    result = true;
  }
  // console.log("result_" + el.tagName, result)
  return result;
}

function mouseButtonReleased(evt) {
    svgDrawing.style.cursor = null;

    if (drawRectToSelect) {
      const box = document.querySelector('#temp_selection');
      for (i=0; i < svg_children.length; i++){
        //svg_children[i].classList.add("selected");
        console.log(svg_children[i].tagName)
        console.log(svg_children[i].className.baseVal)
        child_rect = svg_children[i].getBoundingClientRect();
        console.log(child_rect);        

        //calculate elements inside rectangle
        if (elementIsInside(svg_children[i], box )){
          if (svg_children[i].className.baseVal.includes('selected')){

          } else {
            svg_children[i].className.baseVal += " selected";
            svg_children[i].className.animVal += " selected";
          }
        } else {          
          if (svg_children[i].className.baseVal.includes('selected')){
            console.log("true")
            svg_children[i].className.baseVal = svg_children[i].className.baseVal.replace(" selected"," ");
            svg_children[i].className.animVal = svg_children[i].className.animVal.replace(" selected"," ");
            console.log(svg_children[i].className.baseVal);
          } else {
            console.log("false")
            console.log(svg_children[i].className.baseVal);
          }
        }              
      }                  
      //Delete selection-rectangle
      drawRectToSelect.remove();
      drawRectToSelect = null;
    }
}

function getPointFromEvent(evt) {
    if (evt.targetTouches) {
        point.x = evt.targetTouches[0].clientX;
        point.y = evt.targetTouches[0].clientY;
    } else {
        point.x = evt.clientX;
        point.y = evt.clientY;
    }
    var invertedSVGMatrix = svgDrawing.getScreenCTM().inverse();

    return point.matrixTransform(invertedSVGMatrix);
}
```

Firstly, you have to pass in the event argument to use it later:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  svgDrawing = document.getElementById('drawing');
  svg_rect = svgDrawing.getBoundingClientRect();
  console.log("svg_rect", svg_rect);
  g = document.getElementById("437");
  //svg_children = g.childNodes;
  svg_children = g.querySelectorAll("*");
  console.log(svg_children);
  svgDrawing.addEventListener('pointerdown', e => mouseButtonPressed(e));
  svgDrawing.addEventListener('pointerup', e => mouseButtonReleased(e));
  svgDrawing.addEventListener('pointermove', e => mouseMove(e));
})
```

Then I created a function which tests if the box overlaps at least 1 corner of the element's bounding box:

```
function elementIsInside(el, box){
var result = false;
  el_rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  box_rect = box.getBoundingClientRect();
  // console.log("rects_" + el.tagName, el_rect, box_rect)
  // console.log("rects_" + el.tagName, el, box)
  if (el_rect.right >= box_rect.left && el_rect.right <= box_rect.right
     && el_rect.bottom >= box_rect.top && el_rect.bottom <= box_rect.bottom){
    result = true;
  } else if (el_rect.left >= box_rect.left && el_rect.left <= box_rect.right
     && el_rect.bottom >= box_rect.top && el_rect.bottom <= box_rect.bottom){
    result = true;
  } else if (el_rect.right >= box_rect.left && el_rect.right <= box_rect.right
     && el_rect.top >= box_rect.top && el_rect.top <= box_rect.bottom){
    result = true;
  } else if (el_rect.left >= box_rect.left && el_rect.left <= box_rect.right
     && el_rect.top >= box_rect.top && el_rect.top <= box_rect.bottom){
    result = true;
  }
  // console.log("result_" + el.tagName, result)
  return result;
}
```

And this gets called from your function (and adds or removes the .selected class):

```
function mouseButtonReleased(evt) {
    svgDrawing.style.cursor = null;

    if (drawRectToSelect) {
      const box = document.querySelector('#temp_selection');
      for (i=0; i < svg_children.length; i++){
        //svg_children[i].classList.add("selected");
        console.log(svg_children[i].tagName)
        console.log(svg_children[i].className.baseVal)
        child_rect = svg_children[i].getBoundingClientRect();
        console.log(child_rect);        

        //calculate elements inside rectangle
        if (elementIsInside(svg_children[i], box )){
          if (svg_children[i].className.baseVal.includes('selected')){

          } else {
            svg_children[i].className.baseVal += " selected";
            svg_children[i].className.animVal += " selected";
          }
        } else {          
          if (svg_children[i].className.baseVal.includes('selected')){
            console.log("true")
            svg_children[i].className.baseVal = svg_children[i].className.baseVal.replace(" selected"," ");
            svg_children[i].className.animVal = svg_children[i].className.animVal.replace(" selected"," ");
            console.log(svg_children[i].className.baseVal);
          } else {
            console.log("false")
            console.log(svg_children[i].className.baseVal);
          }
        }              
      }                  
      //Delete selection-rectangle
      drawRectToSelect.remove();
      drawRectToSelect = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks pretty cool. I need some time to understand but first, you passed the e-parameter to the events. I didn't do this and it worked fine. Is there a difference?

I'll be back with new questions after I understood completely, what you did, I think.

Comment: Ahh it seems the event parameter gets passed implicitly, I always passed it explicitly but this answer suggests you don't need to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35936912/9792594 - Great to hear you like my answer. If you liked it and/or it helps you please consider marking it as the correct answer and up-voting it. Look forward to hearing any questions you have!

Comment: I need to select a complete symbol (nested in the g-tag, classed "preview" so this example was a nice help to get this run.  For the symbol-selection, I only had to change the svg_children-selection to document.getElementsByClassName('preview').  thank you, Carsten

Comment: Hi Alex, I added a screenshot and an additional question in my post. Could you please have a look at it?

Comment: You should use ``.classList.add()`` if it works for you. This is the prefered method but in the codePen, I was having errors such as "could not call .add method of null" and when I inspected the elements they had an object for the class rather than a simple string. Something like ``{baseVal: "some-class", AnimVal: "some-class"}`` so I figured it was something you set up. Like a base-class and animated-class.

Comment: Ok, cool. Then I did it the right way. baseVal seems to be something temporary...? Whatever, it works with `.classList.add('classname')`  Thanks again.

Comment: They should be only present when using ``<animate/>`` or ``<animateMotion/>`` tags etc. (SMIL) - then baseVal is to hold the default value and animVal is to hold the current, animated value. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5889988/9792594 - I was also a bit confused as I did not see any of these animation tags in your HTML. Therefore, ``.classList.add()`` is definitely the best way to go if possible :)