# how to scale the element created by use by keeping the fixed position in svg

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I want to scale the element created by use by keeping the fixed position in svg. 
I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945951/how-to-scale-the-element-by-keeping-the-fixed-position-in-svg) 
but my element is created by use  
so it shows  
[image: [![scaleerror]] 
<strike>Simply I can remove the old one and create a new one ,but I feel this a bit trouble.</strike> 
<strike>So I wonder whether it exists any convenient way?</strike>

```
 function tableBindMouseClick(parametersObject)
{
    var table = document.getElementById("PointsTable");
    var length = $('#PointsTable tbody tr').length;//get table rows number


    for(var  i =0;i<length;i++)
    {
        var id = i;
        $($('#PointsTable tbody tr')[i]).bind('click',
            (function(id)
            {
                return function()
                {
                    var p = parametersObject.pointArray[id];
                    var x = p[0] -5;//coordinate x
                    var y = p[1] -5;//coordinate y
                    var icon = document.getElementById("point"+id);
                    icon.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", "translate("+-x+"," + -y +")   scale(3) translate("+x+","+y+")");

                };
            })(id));
    }
```

I do not know whether it is enough.
I am still modifying it.It can run but its effect is still incorrect.

The result [image]
I can not see the error...

PS:Unfortunately,I use the defs element instead of symbol element to create icon.I also want to know difference in them,including g element.

Comment: please show some code

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara I complete it but I think that answer is not good ...

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara I mean we don't need to move to the origin (0, 0),just  scale and translate it.If scale(n),translate ( (1-n)cx,(1-n)cy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I complete it by this parameters:
icon.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", "translate("+-2*x+"," + -2*y +")" + "  scale(3)" );

I think the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945951/how-to-scale-the-element-by-keeping-the-fixed-position-in-svg) makes some mistakes...

This example may make sense.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<title>Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG) 1.1 (Second Edition)</title>
</head>
<body>


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     version="1.1" width="5000" height="5000" viewBox="0 0 5000 5000">

     <rect x="100" y="100" width="30" height="30" stroke="black"    fill="transparent" stroke-width="5"/>

     <rect x="100" y="100" width="30" height="30" stroke="black" fill="transparent" stroke-width="5"
transform ="translate(-230,-230 ) scale(3)" />

</svg>
</body>
</html>
```