# Dynamically flexible path between two points in SVG

Tags: javascript, svg

Hi can some one help me bend path like here
[image]

[here u can see it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/codepo8/bAwUf/) (it's almost what i need, but it on canvas)


**QUESTION**
how i can calculate it? 
which formula describes this 
and how correctly to describe the parameters 'd' of path
here's my code (maybe it needs some improvements?)

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);


app.controller("ctrl", function ($scope) {
  var lineGraph = d3.select("#container").append("svg:svg").attr("width", '100%').attr("height", '100%'); 
  $scope.linesArr = [];
  $scope.blocksArr = [{
    id: 0,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    lineToID: [2]
  },{
    id: 1,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    lineToID: [0,2]
  },{
    id: 2,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    lineToID: []
  }];

  $scope.createLines = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.blocksArr.length; i++){
      if($scope.blocksArr[i].lineToID.length){
        for(var j = 0; j < $scope.blocksArr[i].lineToID.length; j++){
          $scope.linesArr[$scope.blocksArr[i].id + ":"+j] = (lineGraph.append("svg:line"));
        }
      }
    }
  };
  $scope.createLines();

  $scope.checkPoints = function(){

    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.blocksArr.length; i++){
      $scope.blocksArr[i].x = parseInt(document.querySelector('#b' + i).style.left) + (document.querySelector('#b' + i).offsetWidth / 2);
      $scope.blocksArr[i].y = parseInt(document.querySelector('#b' + i).style.top) + (document.querySelector('#b' + i).offsetHeight / 2);

      if($scope.blocksArr[i].lineToID.length){
        for(var j = 0; j < $scope.blocksArr[i].lineToID.length; j++){
          $scope.linesArr[$scope.blocksArr[i].id+":"+j]
            .attr("x1", $scope.blocksArr[$scope.blocksArr[i].id].x)
            .attr("y1", $scope.blocksArr[$scope.blocksArr[i].id].y)
            .attr("x2", $scope.blocksArr[$scope.blocksArr[i].lineToID[j]].x)
            .attr("y2", $scope.blocksArr[$scope.blocksArr[i].lineToID[j]].y)
            .style("stroke", "rgb(6,120,155)");
          //console.log();
        }
      }
    }
  };


  $scope.dragOptions = {
    start: function(e) {
      //console.log("STARTING");
    },
    drag: function(e) {
      $scope.checkPoints();

      //console.log("DRAGGING");
    },
    stop: function(e) {
      //console.log("STOPPING");
    },
    container: 'container'
  }


});












app.directive('ngDraggable', function($document) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      dragOptions: '=ngDraggable'
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
      var startX, startY, x = 0, y = 0,
          start, stop, drag, container;

      var width  = elem[0].offsetWidth,
          height = elem[0].offsetHeight;

      // Obtain drag options
      if (scope.dragOptions) {
        start  = scope.dragOptions.start;
        drag   = scope.dragOptions.drag;
        stop   = scope.dragOptions.stop;
        var id = scope.dragOptions.container;
        if (id) {
          container = document.getElementById(id).getBoundingClientRect();
        }
      }

      // Bind mousedown event
      elem.on('mousedown', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        startX = e.clientX - elem[0].offsetLeft;
        startY = e.clientY - elem[0].offsetTop;
        $document.on('mousemove', mousemove);
        $document.on('mouseup', mouseup);
        if (start) start(e);
      });

      // Handle drag event
      function mousemove(e) {
        y = e.clientY - startY;
        x = e.clientX - startX;
        setPosition();
        if (drag) drag(e);
      }

      // Unbind drag events
      function mouseup(e) {
        $document.unbind('mousemove', mousemove);
        $document.unbind('mouseup', mouseup);
        if (stop) stop(e);
      }

      // Move element, within container if provided
      function setPosition() {
        if (container) {
          if (x < container.left) {
            x = container.left;
          } else if (x > container.right - width) {
            x = container.right - width;
          }
          if (y < container.top) {
            y = container.top;
          } else if (y > container.bottom - height) {
            y = container.bottom - height;
          }
        }

        elem.css({
          top: y + 'px',
          left:  x + 'px'
        });
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
html,body, #container{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.box{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #c07f7f;
  text-align: center;
  background: #f3f4ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div ng-controller="ctrl" ng-app="app" id="container">
  <div class="box" id="b{{$index}}" ng-repeat="i in blocksArr" ng-draggable='dragOptions' ng-style="{top: blocksArr[$index].y, left: blocksArr[$index].x}">{{$index}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please edit your question to put your code in the question (not only at another site). Then, please clarify your question. What part are you having trouble with? Can you make static SVG that looks like what you want? Do you not know how to make SVG look like your desire? What are your getting to do, and what's going wrong?

Comment: hi. tnx.
now it better?

Comment: You have included your code (good job), but you still have not described your problem, what you want (specifically) and what your problem is.

Comment: @Phrogz now all cool?

Comment: So, when you say "bend" a path, do you mean that you want the straight red line to become a curve? Or do you want simply to drag points around to move the corners of a right triangle with straight lines?

Comment: @Phrogz yes i mean need to curve red line (like green+blue) also all points will be draggble.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing, I'm thinking that what you want is to:

- Show two points on screen.
- Calculate an axis-aligned right triangle that touches those points.
- Draw a triangle for the fill and colored lines for the edges of the triangles.
- Allow the user to use the mouse to click and drag the points to new locations.
- Dynamically update the right triangle based on those points.

It is unclear which part of the above you are having trouble with (other than, perhaps, "all of it"). In general, computer programming is about identifying what you want to do, breaking it down into simple steps (as I did above) and then working on those steps one at a time.

1. Can you calculate two 'random' points on screen? (Hint: `Math.random()` might be appropriate, or else you can just pick two fixed starting locations.)
2. Can you draw two points on screen? (Hint: You can use a SVG `<circle>` and adjust the `cx` and `cy` attributes.)
3. Can you calculate where the third point should be? (Hint: one way is to use the 'x' value of one point and the 'y' value of the other point.)
4. Can you draw a filled triangle between these points? (Hint: an easy way is to use an SVG `<polygon>` and adjust the `points` attribute.)
5. Can you draw three lines for the edges? (Hint: use `<line>` or `<polyline>` elements that are later in the document than the `<polygon>` so that they draw on top...but have the `<circle>` elements even lower in the document so that the circles draw on top of everything else.)
6. Can you make it so that when the user clicks and drags on the circles they stay under the mouse? (Hint: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5223921/405017) and example of mine, or go Google about making SVG elements draggable.)
7. During your drag handler, can you recalculate your triangle and points and lines and update them all? (Hint: you can either use `setAttribute()` to update attributes of SVG elements, e.g. `setAttribute(myPoly,'points',arrayOfPoints.join())`, or you can use [SVG DOM bindings](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/shapes.html#InterfaceSVGPolygonElement)—e.g. `myPoly.getItem(0).x = 43`.)

Your question is too broad and vague currently. Either edit this question to make it specific to your exact desire and the exact code that is not working for you, or create a new question that is similarly targeted. Your code snippet does basically nothing useful for all the code you have in there.