# Interactjs with SVG

Tags: javascript, svg

I am using Interactjs to drag SVG elements around an SVG viewport, mostly because of it's support for gestures which I will eventually use for rotation on mobile.  But I am having a problem with simple dragging.

```
<div class="container">
   <!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
   <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
     <g class="shape" transform="scale(0.1) translate(-300, 0) rotate(10)">
       <polygon xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" points="350,75  379,161 469,161 397,215                     423,301 350,250 277,301 303,215                     231,161 321,161" />
     </g>
   </svg>
</div>
```

Interactjs doesn't give the current cursor x,y,so it is computed from a delta x,y, (event.dx, event.dy) accumulated over events, offset from the starting position (event.x0, event.y0).  I then translate this into local coordinates for the target element (in case it has been rotated, skewed, etc.) (as per this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5223921/5610106)) before applying it as a translation transform upon the element's current transform.

```
interact('.shape').draggable({
  onstart: dragStartListener,
  onmove: dragMoveListener,
  onend: dragEndListener
});

var svg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();

function dragStartListener(event) {
  event.target.transform.baseVal.consolidate();
  console.clear();
}

function dragMoveListener(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  var currentCursor = getCurrentCursor(event);
  var translationMatrix = getMatrixForTranslation(target, currentCursor.x, currentCursor.y);
  target.transform.baseVal.getItem(0).setMatrix(target.transform.baseVal.getItem(0).matrix.multiply(translationMatrix));
}

function dragEndListener(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  target.removeAttribute('data-x');
  target.removeAttribute('data-y');
}

function getMatrixForTranslation(target, x, y) {
  return target.ownerSVGElement.createSVGMatrix().translate(x, y);
}

function getCurrentCursor(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  // keep the change in cursor on page in the data-x/data-y attributes
  var x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + event.dx;
  var y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + event.dy;
  target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
  target.setAttribute('data-y', y);
  pt.x = event.x0 + x; // calculate the new whole page coordinates
  pt.y = event.y0 + y;
  // convert to object space coordinates  ...  https://stackoverflow.com/a/5223921/5610106
  var globalPoint = pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
  var globalToLocal = target.getTransformToElement(svg).inverse();
  var inObjectSpace = globalPoint.matrixTransform(globalToLocal);
  console.log('cursor: x: ' + inObjectSpace.x + '; y: ' + inObjectSpace.y);
  return {x: inObjectSpace.x, y: inObjectSpace.y};
}
```

JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/spamhole/rycy07s4/).

I am manipulating the element's "transform" attribute, via target.transform.baseVal.getItem(0).setMatrix(), rather than via CSS transforms since I need the units to be in the same units of the SVG space.  Also, I can easily consolidate() them into a single matrix I can send back to the server so the shapes can be rendered easily on other views.

But simple dragging is causing a large jump on first event, and then the target element, while following the cursor, is not under the cursor.

Any ideas on how I should be doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I did this some time ago:

```
<script>
      var ns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
      var svg = document.createElementNS( ns,'svg')
          svg.id = 'svg'
          svg.style.height = '100%'
          svg.style.width = '100%'

          rect = document.createElementNS( ns,'rect')
            rect.setAttribute('width', '100px')
            rect.setAttribute('height', '100px')
            rect.setAttribute('fill', 'green')
          svg.append(rect )
        document.body.append(svg)


        svg = document.getElementById('svg')

        var mousedown = false;

        window.onmousemove = (e) => {
        var x = e.clientX
        var y = e.clientY

            svg.onmousedown = (e) => {
                var x = e.clientX
                var y = e.clientY
                    diffX = Math.abs(e.target.getBoundingClientRect().left - x)
                    diffY = Math.abs(e.target.getBoundingClientRect().top - y ) 
                console.log(diffY +' || '+e.target.getBoundingClientRect().top+' || '+y)

                mousedown = true;
            }

            if(mousedown) {
                e.target.setAttribute('x', x - diffX) 
                e.target.setAttribute('y', y - diffY)
                window.onmouseup = () => {
                    mousedown = false;
                }
            }
        }
  </script>
```

Comment: your solution won't take account of transformations on the rectangle before dragging.  Try adding "rect.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(50 0) rotate(45)')" when setting up the <rect> and you'll see the rectangle no longer follows the mouse, because there is no account of the mouse position in object space coordinates.  Also, I can't manipulate x & y attributes, since <g> tags don't have them, hence why I am trying to manipulate the transform attribute.